# what to write in data parameter of JS ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

The goal of my project is a website that can show a list of addresses that updates without refreshing which means I have to use AJAX. I hope to include Javascript. the current code I have is the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#get-data').click(function () {
        var showData = $('#show-data');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'json.json',

        })
    })
})
```

while looking at the $.ajax() I've seen the data parameter often used but I have no clue what it's purpose is or what I should insert into it. I've read multiple documentations yet I still don't understand what I'm supposed to write in the data parameter. I've looked at different StackOverflow questions aswell but they haven't brought me any further.

It'd be helpful if someone could help me with this. I'm having quite some problems just trying to figure out AJAX Calls in general.

Comment: The `data` property of the request is simply the information you want to send to the server in the request. Exactly what that data is depends on what the purpose of the request is. We can't really give you any more information than that.

Comment: so you can't tell me what gets sent or what info this is supposed to be? is it even needed generally?

Comment: What gets sent? -> The value you put in the property. What info is this supposed to be? -> The information the server needs to complete your request. Is it even needed? -> Depends entirely on what you're doing. Imagine the AJAX request is a telephone call. The `data` attribute is the words you speak to the person at the other end. What those words are depend who you're calling and what you want to tell them.

Answer (score 0):

From https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.
>   Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the
>   traditional setting.

Depending on your backend, you can then access this data while processing the request.
For example if your backend was Laravel (PHP) you could do:

```
$request->input('yourDataParameterGoesHere')
```

And that would give you the data you passed in the ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Here an example

```
var par={
         key: value,
         key2: value2,
         key3: [value0of4, value1of4, value2of4]
};
$.ajax({
         type: "POST", // GET(Request) or POST(Submit) 
            url: 'https://www.google.it/', //Where your data will go 
            data:JSON.stringify(par), //data parameter
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", //identify output
            success: function (response) {
                //This function will run if the ajax call goes on success
                alert("OK!");
                //if your function provides a return:
                var ris = response.d;
                console.log(ris)//just for a check
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("failure");
                var ris = response.d;
                console.log(ris)
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error");
                var ris = response.d;
                console.log(ris)
            }
        });
```

If something goes wrong, always check the console